# Unlocked iPhone 5 on Verizon

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I just bought an unlocked iPhone 5 and I already own an iPhone 5 on Verizon.

I am transferring the cellular service from my old iPhone 5 to the new iPhone 5 which, from my knowledge, just involves moving the SIM card from old to new. From my knowledge, 4G SIM cards are automatic and refresh every 30 seconds. I proceeded to transfer the card from old to new.

This DID NOT WORK and after talking with Verizon, they said they do not support an unlocked iPhone 5; yet, the Apple store told me I could use this phone perfectly fine with Verizon. Conflicting information much?

I'm not sure where else to ask this question because I feel like I should be able to activate the phone myself from what I've read, but it still is not activating. I don't really want to deal with Verizon or Apple at this point because of the conflict.

Can I use this phone? If so, what am I doing wrong? Or do I need to return it to Apple and get the right phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Apple web site:

> The unlocked iPhone includes all the features of iPhone but without a wireless contract commitment. You can activate and use iPhone on the supported GSM wireless network of your choice, such as AT&T in the United States. The unlocked iPhone 4, iPhone 4S and iPhone 5 will not work with CDMA-based carriers such as Verizon Wireless or Sprint.

So the genius led you astray.